# Exception when using Convert.ToDouble

Tags: c#

I am making an inventory program that requires the user to input various amounts of different items that they would like to purchase. I use this line to convert the number of items into doubles so I can calculate but I get an error stating that i have an unhandled format exception, that the input string was not in the correct format. Is there something that I am missing?

```
itembatteries = Convert.ToDouble(txtNumberofBatteries.Text);
```

Comment: Convert.ToDouble fails if the input string is not in the correct format to be converted to a double. And the correct format depends on your locale settings Use double.TryParse instead. By the way it is all written on MSDN and doing a little search before asking here is always the best path

Comment: What's the string causing it? If it's not a double, that's why.

Comment: What are you typing into the text box? Also, based on your textbox name, you probably want to convert it to an `int` instead of a `double`, since it's very hard to have half a battery.

Comment: What's the input? You probably have spaces or something in your input.

Comment: @DaveZych Reminds me of the Simpsons episode where Homer whittle's down a D battery to a AAA :)

Comment: [C# MSDN Convert.ToDouble](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx) you should have saved yourself the headache and done a simple google search

Comment: i used double because i will calculate with price which has to be a double because of the cents.

Comment: Well price should actually probably be `decimal`, not `double` and I'm not sure why the price having cents affects the battery count? You want someone to be able to type in 2.3 batteries?

Comment: These kind of formatting and parsing problems can easily be avoided if you use [object binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial) instead of assigning and reading manually to and from textboxes.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Assuming the OP is using WinForms

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. This will stop the exception if txtNumberofBatteries.Text is not a valid string representation of a double.

For example:

```
double itembatteries;
if (double.TryParse(txtNumberofBatteries.Text, out itembatteries))
{
    //Something with itembatteries
}
else
{
    //Show Error: you didn't type a number
}
```

Comment: That will suppress the error from the Convert.ToDouble, but it won't help the OP turn the TextBox.Text into a double.

Comment: How so, `itembatteries` will contain the value from the text box?

Comment: So why doesn't Convert.ToDouble(txtNumberofBatteries.Text) work?